# “Es gibt nichts zu essen” or “es gibt nichts zum Essen”?

Tags: word-usage, preposition, infinitive

As the title says. Are both forms correct? Are there differences in meaning?
Would it work with, e.g., *tun*?

> Ich habe nichts zum Tun

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26368/es-ist-zeit-zu-essen-zum-essen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, “Es gibt nichts zu essen” means there is nothing to eat, while “Es gibt nichts zum Essen” is also correct but with a second meaning. You could interpret “Es gibt nichts zum Essen (dazu)” with an implied “dazu”, as in there is no side dish — nothing extra. But that depends on the context and is seldom used.

As for “Ich habe nichts zum Tun”: *zum* is a contraction of *zu dem*. Alone as a sentence, it does not make much sense in German. I’m a native speaker and can’t really tell you the grammatical background here, but it is my feeling that something is missing in the sentence. If people were talking about a certain deed and somebody said “Ich habe nichts zum Tun zu sagen”, then it would mean, he has no comments on the deed of somebody else.

Answer (score 8):

*Nichts zum Essen* only works because apart from *essen* being an infinitive, *Essen* is also a noun meaning meal. “Es gibt nichts zum Essen” = “There is nothing for the meal”, i.e. “There is nothing at meal-time”. In English you would normally specify the kind of meal and say something like “There is nothing for lunch.” Since in most plausible contexts there are no similar periodically recurring occasions for *tun (doing)*, *zum Tun* cannot be interpreted this way. Lots of people still say it that way at least occasionally, but that’s a colloquial or dialectal variant of *zu tun* that is considered wrong in standard German.

Answer (score 4):

Both forms,

> Es gibt nichts zu essen.

and

> es gibt nichts zum Essen.

are right, as *essen* is a verb and *zu essen* translates into *to eat* while *Essen* is a noun which could be translated into *there is no food.*
But you cannot do that with *zu tun*, as *tun* is a german irregular verb for *do* and there is no noun which is spelled *tun*. So in that case, only *Es gibt nichts zu tun* is right, which translates into *There is nothing to do*.

Comment: Why does "zum Essen" (in the sense of food/meal) work?

Comment: Because "etwas zum Essen" means "something edible".

Comment: There is the noun "[Tun](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tun_Beschaeftigung_Handlung)" just as there is the noun doing in English. "It was not their doing" as in they did not do the deed. "Es war nicht ihr Tun."

Comment: @Grantwalzer... good question. My theory is that it has something to do with the "tangible-ness". If you have something "zu essen" that means you have some real world item that is edible. "tun" on the contrary refers to activities. "Ich esse eine Pizza", ja. "Ich tue ein Auto", nein. "tun" hat also nichts mit Substantiven zu tun, und daher funktioniert es nicht. Nur eine Theorie

Answer (score -1):

As a side note, while

> Es gibt nichts zum Tun

does not normally make much sense in written german, it is quite commonly used in austrian german dialects.

Comment: This is incredibly close to being a comment rather than an answer.