# „Es ist Zeit zu essen/zum Essen“

Tags: verb, preposition

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26355/how-to-say-now-its-something-time) hat mich zum Grübeln gebracht. Es ist Essenszeit, also

> Ist es jetzt Zeit zu essen

oder heißt es

> Ist es jetzt Zeit zum Essen

?

Ich hätte ja gedacht, *zu essen* ist richtig, aber *zum Essen* ist laut [Google fight](http://www.googlefight.com/es+ist+zeit+zu+essen-vs-es+ist+zeit+zum+essen.php) beliebter. Hat die Masse hier recht?

Comment: Googlefight funzt eh nicht richtig. Laut der Seite ist "Es ist Zeit zum Gehen" der Sieger, aber in einer herrkömlichen Google-Suche stets 62.000:3.600 zu Gunsten von "zu gehen". Im Falle von "zu Essen" vs "zum Essen" ist es ein Unentschieden.

Comment: gut zu wissen @EM1

Comment: Beides ist richtig, sowie das Englische _time to eat_ vs. _time for eating_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fest steht, dass beide Ausdrücke im deutschen Sprachgebrauch angewandt werden. Somit wird dich auch jeder verstehen, wenn du diese Phrasen benutzt.

Laut Duden ist allerdings der erste Satz „Es ist Zeit zu essen“ grammatikalisch richtig, während der zweite Ausdruck „zum Essen“ so erstmal nicht im Duden zu finden ist. Da ich diesen Ausdruck in Deutschland jedoch schon oft gehört habe, ist er eher unter Umgangssprache einzuordnen. Also: benutzen kann man beides, schöner ist jedoch dein erster Vorschlag.

Googlefight mag in dieser Hinsicht sogar Recht haben. Umgangssprache ist nun einmal beliebt.

Answer (score 1):

Du musst hier zwei Dinge unterscheiden.

> Es ist jetzt Zeit zu essen.

bedeutet, dass genau jetzt die Zeit ist, wo wir zu essen haben.

Im Gegensatz dazu steht der Satz

> Es ist jetzt Zeit zum Essen.

Dieser besagt schlicht, dass wir im Moment (ausreichend) Zeit haben, um zu essen. Ob wir nun tatsächlich essen werden oder nicht, ist unerheblich.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Sätze ganz anders …

Comment: Die Sätze verstehe ich nicht so, vielmehr sind in beiden Fällen mE beide Lesarten möglich.